# React navigation 6 - navigating from one stack A to stack screen B - why screen B wont call useEffect (but renders)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-v6

I have a nested tabs navigator inside a stack navigator.

- When I navigate from Tab Screen A to Stack Screen B, B's useEffect is called, all good.
- When I navigate from Stack Screen C to also Stack Screen B, B's useEffect is NOT called. I dont understand why.
  -I am able to navigate to Screen B from both Screens, thats not the problem. I also am able to pass params. The only thing is just the useEffect is not called when coming from C, coming from A works fine.

I use in both cases same:

```
 <Button title="goTo" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SearchResults', {id: id})}/>
```

I also tried to use useIsFocused and useFocusEffect, but its also not called when I navigate from stack screen C. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
It seems that the problem is with navigating to Screen C (from which I try to navigate to Screen B (that doesnt mount) is that I defined it in the header of Tab Navigator. If I wouldnt, I could navigate to C and C would mount. But I dont understand why that is or what to do.
So In my code : When I navigate from NotificationsScreen to SearchResultsScreen, SearchScreen wont mount (as it seems its because I access NotificationsScreen from header of tabs navigator)

```
const MyTabs = (props) => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerRight: (props) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Notifications")}>
                            <Icon name="notifications"/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            }}
        >    
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
            />  
            <Tab.Screen 
          // when I navigate from SearchScreen to SearchResultsScreen, SearchResultsScreen useEffect is called
                name="Search"
                component={SearchScreen}
            />     
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

```
const MyStack = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Tabs">
                    {(props) => <MyTabs {...props}  />}
                </Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen
                    name="SearchResults"
                    component={SearchResultsScreen}
                />
            <Stack.Screen
                    name="Notifications"
                    component={NotificationsScreen}
            // when I navigate from NotificationsScreen to SearchResultsScreen, SearchResultsScreen useEffect is NOT called
                />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in **Notifications** component

```
navigation.replace("SearchResults", null, null)
```

Comment: try to rerender this screen with {id:id}

Comment: that does not work either. It seems that the problem is with any screen I have also defined in the header of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

use `**useFocusEffect**` on screen B to rerender every time the screen is focused
Here is the link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(user));

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```

Comment: No that dosnt work, I have tried it previously. Again the problem is with from where I access Screen C, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

because Stack screen B component is mounted when you first navigate to it and it calls useEffect, then you navigate to screen C, here B is not unmounted that's why when you navigate to Screen B again it is already mounted so useEffect does not executes.
you just need to unmount Screen B like following

```
useEffect(()=>{
//useEffect stuff on mount

return () => {
        //  on component unmount.
    }
},[])
```

Comment: no I dont navigate to it. First time I navigate is from screen C and it is never mounted